# Plot time series data by first counting frequency using pandas and matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset of emailers and receivers with timestamps.

For the top three emailers, I want to plot the number of unique emails by `sender`, `day`, `year`, `month`, and `week_year`

It seems to me, that first I will have to use groupby to compute the relevant summaries, and then plot the same, or is there a way to do so directly?

Normally, if I did not have to do the frequency first, I could have plotted the values directly, by using the timestamp column as index.

I am kind of stuck here, with this need to compute frequency first.

I was able to do the following.

#### Setup dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_in = pd.DataFrame({
'sender':['Able Boy','Able Boy','Able Boy','Mark L. Taylor','Mark L. Taylor',
    'Mark L. Taylor','scott kirk','scott kirk','scott kirk','scott kirk',
    'Able Boy','Able Boy','james h. madison','james h. madison','james h. madison',
    'james joyce','james joyce','james joyce','james joyce','james joyce',
    'scott kirk','Able Boy'],
'receiver':['Toni Z. Zapata','Mark Angel','Johnny C. Cash','paul a boyd','michelle fam',
    'debbie bradford','Mark Angel','Johnny C. Cash','Able Boy','Mark L. Taylor',
    'jenny chang','julie s. smith', 'hillary t. young', 'tiffany r.','Able Boy',
    'Mark Angel','Able Boy','julie s. smith','jenny chang','debbie bradford',
    'Able Boy','Toni Z. Zapata'],
'time':[911929000000,911929000000,910228000000,911497000000,911497000000,
    911932000000,914261000000,914267000000,914269000000,914276000000,
    914932000000,915901000000,916001000000,916001000000,916001000000,
    947943000000,947943000000,947943000000,947943000000,947943000000,
    916001000000,911929100000],
'email_ID':['<A34E5R>','<A34E5R>','<B34E5R>','<C34E5R>','<C34E5R>',
    '<C36E5R>','<C36E5A>','<C36E5B>','<C36E5C>','<C36E5D>',
    '<D000A0>','<D000A1>','<D000A2>','<D000A2>','<D000A2>',
    '<D000A3>','<D000A3>','<D000A3>','<D000A3>','<D000A3>',
    '<D000A4>','<A34E5S>']
})
```

#### Transform dataframe:

```
df_1 = df_in.copy()
df_1['week_year'] = df_1['time'].apply(lambda x:"%d/%d" %(x.year,x.week))
df_1 = df_1.set_index('time')

df_1['year'] = df_1.index.year
df_1['week'] = df_1.index.week
df_1['date'] = df_1.index.date
df_1['hour'] = df_1.index.hour
df_1['day'] = df_1.index.day
df_1['month'] = df_1.index.month
df_1['weekday_name'] = df_1.index.weekday_name

df_grp_1 = (df_1.groupby(['sender','year']).email_ID.nunique())
print("\nGROUP BY SENDER AND YEAR:")
print(df_grp_1)
print(type(df_grp_1))

df_grp_2 = (df_1.groupby(['sender','date']).email_ID.nunique())
print("\nGROUP BY SENDER AND DATE:")
print(df_grp_2)
print(type(df_grp_2))

df_grp_3 = (df_1.groupby(['sender','week_year']).email_ID.nunique())
print("\nGROUP BY SENDER AND week_year:")
print(df_grp_3)
print(type(df_grp_3))
```

Comment: by day will be a little busy?

Comment: yes, but still useful visualization for audience